# Adding text in NSString in first place

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I need to add constant text to NSString and pass it to my method. The idea is that i need to have "*X1*"and afterwards goes string which is dynamic. How should i fuse them to one string?

Well, here is the code, maybe it will be much clearer than my explanation of that I am trying to do.

```
 NSString *name = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"Name"];
 [self sendSMS:[@"*X1*%@" name]];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% clear on what you're asking but does this help?

```
NSString *name = [@"X1" stringByAppendingString:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"Name"]];
[self sendSMS:name];
```

Comment: Yup, thats exactly what i wanted. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You have a lot of options to do that

You can use NSString stringWithFormat, for example.

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"X1%@", name];
```

But I really advise you to study the [NSString class](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) to know what is the best choice for you. Not only for this case, but for all the future cases that you will face developing.

Some option to your code are:

```
NSString *name = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"Name"];
[self sendSMS:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"X11%@",name]];
```

or

```
NSMutableString *name = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"Name"];
[name insertString:@"X11" atIndex:0];
[self sendSMS:name];
```

Comment: Your format has two placeholders but you only supply one value. That  can result in a crash at runtime.